# Find the smallest value of $f(x, y, z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the smallest value of $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(y - x)^2 + 4} +\sqrt{(z - y)^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(10 - z)^2 + 9}$

I found this question while looking from some exam papers and have no idea how to approach this. Would using partials work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution under the assumption that $0<x<y<z<10$.  I do not know if my answer is still correct without this assumption.  **Edit**.  It is.  See comment by JimmyK.

By drawing a diagram, you can see that $f(x,y,z)$ is the total distance of a chain of straight line segments going from $(0,0)$ to $(10,7)$ via the points $(x,1),\,(y,3),\,(z,4)$.  Clearly the minimum value is the straight line distance
$$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{149}\ ,$$
achieved if and only if
$$x=\frac{10}{7}\ ,\quad y=\frac{30}{7}\ ,\quad z=\frac{40}{7}\ .$$

Comment: You have a chain of line segments going from $(0,0)$, to some point on the line $y = 1$, to some point on $y = 3$, to some point on $y = 4$ to $(10,7)$. By the triangle inequality, the shortest sum of distances is still the straight line distance. So, that assumption isn't needed.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Take the 3 partial derivatives and set them to zero. Solve the resulting system of equations for the critical points.

Comment: That is not a practical method in this case...

Comment: Did you try ? If you did, I suppose you enjoyed a nightmare. Cheers.